# Are questions about Visual Studio errors on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I have seen many questions like:

- Visual Studio license error
- Visual Studio 2015 components are unavailable

Are these on-topic?

Comment: Yes, but mostly are pointless.  I created a dupe target for these types of quesitons.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the question, but in general, yes. According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions about

> software tools commonly used by programmers

are on-topic. So, as long as the question is sufficiently detailed and meets other Stack Overflow standards (e.g. decent English), it's fine.